# ntfsresize -b -f not working chkdsk /r freezing

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, ext4

I've got a failing hard drive. Don't have the funds atm to buy a new hard drive. So I need to hold up. My main operating system is now ubuntu which is able to run the hard drive fine without any problems.

I have ext4, though for some files on the ntfs partition it runs into problems and may cause to freeze up. I've ran programs like HD Regenerator, but to fix my hard drive completely with that it would take over a week of non-stop running.

If I try to boot into windows safe mode it freezes up after 20 seconds, can still move the mouse, but nothing responds if I click. So I need to move my ntfs files onto a ext4 partition, I have not seen any corruption on ext4 even though I've been using as my primary for quite some time.

`425gb NTFS, 46gb ext4, 4gb linux swap file data is how it's arranged`

On my hard drive I am just looking to recover the most important stuff like documents. Bunch of pdf's, djvu, odt close to 50gb worth of stuff. There's about 80gb worth of free ntfs space which I'm unable to use atm.

Booting the windows 7 installation disk, running chkdsk /f checks out fine with no problems, with 112kb of bad sectors. chkdsk /r freezed at the 4th step at 17%.

I need to run this because ntfsresize won't allow me to resize when running the force and force bad sector command.

I set it to: `sudo ntfsresize -f -b -s 345G /dev/sda2`

and get WARNING drive has found 29 bad sectors, must run chkdsk /f before continuing. Something like that, don't feel like booting back into a live cd to get the exact error.

Now one thing I am considering if I cannot shrink this pesky ntfs is to run ntfsundelete as shown [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13706/recover-deleted-files-on-an-ntfs-hard-drive-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/). So my hard partitions would be arranged as so

`ext4 345gb ext4 74gb where I would recover the files from ntfs 46gb ext4 4gb swap file.`

I am concerned that the data might be spread evenly across the sectors for the entire ntfs partition which is why I am asking here first.

How do I shrink this pesky partition or would it be safe to create these two new ext4 partitions in gparted and proceed to run ntfsundelete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messing around with recovery tools while booted from a failing drive is probably never going to work and the more you use that drive the higher the chances of losing all the data on it are.

Running partition resizing and editing can be risky at the best of times (if you lose power in the middle for instance) Doing so on a flaky drive is asking for trouble, which is why the tools won't run if they detect anything out of the ordinary.

If you really care about these files accept you need to buy a new hard drive. If you lost everything on the drive would you care or would you happily pay the cost of a drive to prevent this in hindsight? A new ~350GB drive is pretty cheap.

If you don't care much about the data, really can't replace the drive and insist on running it until the bitter end I suggest messing around with partitioning tools as little as possible. Forget about reclaiming free disk space from the broken partition, you are probably just lucky that your Ubuntu install is in an error free part of the drive (for now). 
Also, forget about ntfsundelete, that works for deleted files on a working drive, not corrupted files in a broken partition.

If you value your data I suggest:

1. Stop using the drive to run the system from!
2. Try and copy the files to another drive while booted from a recovery disk.
3. Otherwise, try and access them from another system. Have you tried installing the drive as a secondary disk in another windows system or connecting it via an external usb case?